# Finding the derivative of the integral using FTOC.

Tags: calculus

[image: Image attached]

Since they're simply asking for the derivative of $h$, would the answer simply be: $$\cos^2 (x) + x$$

Comment: Hi Etree! To get the best possible answer, please be sure to provide the work you have completed so users can know your level of understanding etc. Furthermore, is this from a graded homework assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Define an auxiliary function $$g(x)=\int_{-1}^x (\cos(t^2)+t) \, dt$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $g'(x)=\cos(x^2)+x$.

However, note that $$h(x)=g(\sin(x))$$

Hence by the chain rule:

$$h'(x)=g'(\sin(x))\cos(x)=(\cos(\sin ^2(x))+\sin(x))\cos(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
y=h(x) = \int_{-1}^{\sin x} (\cos(t^2)+t)\,dt
$$
So write
$$
y = \int_{-1}^u (\cos(t^2)+t)\,dt \quad\text{and}\quad u = \sin x.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{dy}{du} = \cos(u^2) + u \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{du}{dx}=\cos x.
$$
So
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx} = (\cos(u^2)+u)\cos x = (\cos(\sin^2 x) + \sin x) \cos x.
$$